# Get further solutions to a query

Tags: prolog, prolog-toplevel

I have

```
assert(user(anna)).
assert(user(tom)).
```

but when I query

```
?- user(X).
```

I only get

```
X = anna.
```

Shouldn't I get another line saying X = tom as well?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to type a semicolon after the first answer:

```
?- user(X).
X = anna ;
X = tom.
```

Comment: Semicolon or `SPACE`, which is much more convenient on many keyboard layouts.